# Convert a simple command into an AST in python

Tags: python, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree, pyparsing

I would like a function in Python that converts a string command into an AST (Abstract Syntax Tree).

The syntax for the command is as follows:

```
commandName(3, "hello", 5.0, x::int)
```

A command can accept any number of comma separated values that can be either

1. Integers
2. Strings
3. Floats
4. Types

Suppose the function is called `convert_to_ast`, then

```
convert_to_ast('commandName(3, "hello", 5.0, x::int)')
```

Should yield the following AST:

```
{ 
  'type': 'command',
  'name': 'commandName',
  'args': [{
    'type': 'int',
    'value': 3
  }, {
    'type': 'str',
    'value': 'Hello'
  }, {
    'type': 'float',
    'value': 5.0
  }, {
    'type': 'var',
    'kind': 'int',
    'name': 'x
  }]
```

Comment: I should clarify: The tuple appears as a string that is part of a larger string, usually a command like 'add(1,"hello",3)'

Comment: I think that the only remaining thing is asking what the _rules_ are for determining what something is.  e.g. what are the rules for saying that `int` is a "type"?  is it the same parsing as a python identifier?  and commands are just identifiers that have () after them?  In that case, you can still possibly parse this using `AST` (which is kind of fun).

Comment: Good question. I've just updated my example to be slightly more complex. I replace the "type" with a "variable". You'll see that now the syntax is not Python anymore. The point is that I will later on add different types of data that this command can accept and the syntax of which shouldn't be tied to Python's syntax.

Comment: Oh, and just for the example, there's nothing funky with all those types of values, it's sorta how it looks like. Integers are just a bunch of digits, Floats are a bunch of digits with a single point in the middle, Strings have quotes, and Variables are just identifier followed by two colons follows by another identifier.

Comment: Do you have a specific question on how to do this? Or do you just want someone to write it for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like you could just evaluate the string and then pick off the types from there:

```
>>> items = ast.literal_eval('(404.5, "Hello", 5)')
>>> [{'type': type(item).__name__, 'value': item} for item in items]
[{'type': 'float', 'value': 404.5}, {'type': 'str', 'value': 'Hello'}, {'type': 'int', 'value': 5}]
```

Of course, if you want to do more interesting things, you can access the AST directly:

```
>>> ast.dump(ast.parse('(404.5, "Hello", 5)'))
"Module(body=[Expr(value=Tuple(elts=[Num(n=404.5), Str(s='Hello'), Num(n=5)], ctx=Load()))])"
>>> ast.parse('(404.5, "Hello", 5)').body[0].value.elts
[<_ast.Num object at 0x107fa1250>, <_ast.Str object at 0x107fa1290>, <_ast.Num object at 0x107fa12d0>]
```

For a more general thing than parsing a tuple (as you've added to the question), we still can use python's AST to parse this (as long as your syntax *is* valid python).  In this case, we'll create an `ast.NodeVisitor` which will pull out the information that we as it visits each node of the python AST that we care about.  In this case, we care about  `Call`, `Num`, `Str` and `Name` nodes:

```
import ast

class Parser(ast.NodeVisitor):

    def __init__(self):
        self.calls = []
        self.current_command = None

    def visit_Call(self, node):
        name = node.func.id
        self.current_command = {
            'type': 'command',
            'name': name,
            'args': []
        }
        self.calls.append(self.current_command)
        for arg in node.args:
            self.visit(arg)
        self.current_command = None

    def visit_Num(self, node):
        if not self.current_command:
            return
        args = self.current_command['args']
        arg = {
            'type': type(node.n).__name__,
            'value': node.n
        }
        args.append(arg)

    def visit_Str(self, node):
        if not self.current_command:
            return
        args = self.current_command['args']
        arg = {
            'type': 'str',
            'value': node.s
        }
        args.append(arg)

    def visit_Name(self, node):
        if not self.current_command:
            return
        args = self.current_command['args']
        arg = {
            'type': 'type',
            'kind': node.id 
        }
        args.append(arg)


S = 'commandName(3, "hello", 5.0, int)'

tree = ast.parse(S)
p = Parser()
p.visit(tree)
print p.calls
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It would work were the tuple completely isolated. I've updated my question to clarify the details. Basically, the tuple usually is part of some larger string, usually as arguments to a command. Furthermore, not all of the types in the tuple will be Python types. I only stated Python types to keep the question simple. 

In any case, for further details I refer to my above edit in the question. And again, thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @TheSeamau5 -- Unfortunately, that's still not all that clear... It seems like you only want the python literals in the result and no entry for `<something_wierd>`?  It seems like a parsing problem where much of the stuff is undefined is a very hard problem indeed :-)

Comment: I apologize. I put the `<something_weird>` there to say that I am looking for a solution that works even for elements that are not Python types. Whatever that type is, I'll figure it out via parsing.

Comment: I will rewrite the question to include the full problem, hopefully that will clarify things. I was just seeking to solve a portion of my problem, but I guess I should just ask for the whole thing.

Comment: I have updated my question to fully reflect my problem. Hopefully it is clear now. Thanks again.